# Dynamically set input type to file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, input-type-file

How can we make the following work when we set the input type to file? [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunluttin/PfMyf/) too.

```
<div ng-app>
    <input ng-model="type" type="radio" value="email" />Email
    <input ng-model="type" type="radio" value="password" />Password
    <input ng-model="type" type="radio" value="file" />File<br/>
        <label>Type:</label> {{ type }}<br/>
    <input type="{{ type }}">
</div>
```

We can switch dynamically between password, email, and text input types but not into a file type.

We have also tried to set the input type to file from a directive. That also doesn't work.

There is probably a time in the DOM rendering lifecycle after which we can no longer set an input type to file. Can angular set the input type to file before it's to late?

Comment: type is a special attribute for the html element input. Select a different attribute name.

Comment: @koolunix Hmm. We can dynamically assign the type to password or email, though. Why is just file forbidden?

Comment: Input is a directive in angular, and I don't think you can switch directive behavior the fly with scope like that.  http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/api/ng.directive:input. Why don't you create 3 inputs and do show/hide of the correct input field, depending on what radio is selected?

Comment: @koolunix Changing to a different attribute name (e.g. myType) doesn't appear to work.